# Communicating with third-party web services from .NET

Tags: wcf, soap-client

In the current project I need to communicate with third-party web services from .NET. The difficult part is constructing SOAP messages and posting to the server. After googling enough I found by using SoapClient class I can easily construct/send/receive soap message but I think for that I've to add references to WSE assemblies and it is kind of obsolete.

Is it the right way to use SoapClient for this scenario or any other better ways there in WCF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the service provides a `.wsdl` file, you can have VS generate strongly-typed proxy/wrapper classes for you by adding a service reference (this is done using the command-line tool `wsdl.exe`). Right-click on your project in Visual Studio and select "Add Service Reference..." and enter the URL of the `.wsdl` file. "Add Service Reference..." will generate client classes with methods and strongly-typed request and response types corresponding to the methods defined in the web service definition. The proxies can be configured to allow both synchronous and asynchronous method invocation.

See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386382.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my client not interested in doing so because they have a system that is very loosely coupled. If we create a predefined proxy that may increase the dependency in the system. So I put my question in other way that is how I can create a soap message quite easily from WCF?

Comment: No problem! How loosely coupled are we talking about here? Is the client supposed to be able to adapt (at runtime) to changes in the "shape" of the web service or individual web service methods? Or, would it be expected that the client would need to be recompiled if there were any changes made to the web service?

Comment: @Mark: I don't think your client fully understands what "loosely coupled" means. Both sides agreeing on the bindings and contracts in advance *is* loose-coupling. If you don't agree on those things in advance, you cannot communicate at all, which is "no coupling". :-)

Comment: As you replied in the answer "Add Service Reference.." will generate strongly-typed client classes and methods.. The system that I'm working currently is built on asp technology that uses XML as main way of communication. I'm not interested in having a set of client classes in the .NET component that I'm creating for the asp application to interact with variety of services.

Comment: @Christian I don't agree with your point. please re-think about that.

Comment: @Mark Can you give more information about web service which you need to communicate with? But in any case you mentioned that "The difficult part is constructing SOAP messages and posting to the server". And you've got an answer - use WCF which can hide this difficulty from you. And please re-think about Christian's point, maybe your question has not enough information to be answered. In this context XML could hardly be characterized as 'main way of communication'.

Comment: I just don't want to have a predefined proxy by adding service reference or one generated through SvcUtil.exe to communicate with the web service. I'm planning to create a SOAP message dynamically and post it to the service. Tell me If I can do that through WCF. Regarding @Christian's point if both sides are very well aware of each other in a system as a general knowledge I say they are more coupled.